# How do I make one list from multiple columns using Python's Pandas?

Tags: python, database, list, pandas

I have database that I want to use make one list of numbers so I can count how many times each number occurs throughout the database. I want to use the columns Number_1 - Number_5. The most I've been able to do is just make separate lists for each column.
To clarify further, I want the list to look something like this:
list_of_numbers = (11,18,5,14,31,26,12,37,12,13,3,2,4,14,41,22,31,26,15,35,32,20,49,20,15,7,5,10,18,58,...)

BTW, the database is pretty big, so the list is going to have 7650 elements to it
It looks something like this:

`Draw # Draw DateNumber_1Number_2Number_3Number_4Number_5Mega
1004 Tue. Feb 03, 2015  11  22  25  58  69  13
1003 Fri. Jan 30, 2015  18  31  39  45  55  6
1002 Tue. Jan 27, 2015  5   26  27  44  57  7
1001 Fri. Jan 23, 2015  14  15  32  68  72  8
1000 Tue. Jan 20, 2015  31  35  56  59  63  6
999 Fri. Jan 16, 2015   26  32  44  45  58  11
998 Tue. Jan 13, 2015   12  20  25  50  51  7
997 Fri. Jan 09, 2015   37  49  50  56  57  8
996 Tue. Jan 06, 2015   12  20  27  38  75  4
995 Fri. Jan 02, 2015   13  15  35  62  74  12
994 Tue. Dec 30, 2014   3   7   44  63  67  12
993 Fri. Dec 26, 2014   2   5   10  20  38  14
992 Tue. Dec 23, 2014   4   10  31  56  66  7
991 Fri. Dec 19, 2014   14  18  58  59  68  4
990 Tue. Dec 16, 2014   41  58  68  72  73  1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
df.iloc[:, -6: -1].values.T.ravel()
```

yields

```
array([11, 18,  5, 14, 31, 26, 12, 37, 12, 13,  3,  2,  4, 14, 41, 18,  5,
       14, 31, 26, 12, 37, 12, 13,  3,  2,  4, 14, 41, 31, 26, 15, 35, 32,
       20, 49, 20, 15,  7,  5, 10, 18, 58, 39, 27, 32, 56, 44, 25, 50, 27,
       35, 44, 10, 31, 58, 68, 45, 44, 68, 59, 45, 50, 56, 38, 62, 63, 20,
       56, 59, 72, 55, 57, 72, 63, 58, 51, 57, 75, 74, 67, 38, 66, 68, 73,
        6,  7,  8,  6, 11,  7,  8,  4, 12, 12, 14,  7,  4,  1])
```

You can call the `tolist()` method on the resulting array if you prefer lists.